# C tailq queue substitution for performance issues

Tags: c, queue

I have a tailq with 100k+ entries of this struct:

```
struct entry {
char *file_name;
FILE *file;
TAILQ_ENTRY(entry) tailq;
};
```

The purpose is store thousands of file pointers for an application creates thousands of files and append stuffs to them.

On each increase of the tailq I have a foreach:

```
int c;
char temp[20];

struct entry *np;

TAILQ_FOREACH(np, &tailq_head[y], tailq) {
    if(strcmp(np->file_name, temp) == 0){
        c = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

That searches for some temp name that already is on the tailq, if it isn't in the tail then add id, else do not.

What can I do to improve performance? What is the faster structure that I can use? Should I calculate an integer hash to the temp variable to be compared in the foreach? Ideas?

Comment: Does the order of the files matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping an integer hash of the name in each entry will speed up the compare by a significant amount. It will also save one level of pointer indirection. But you're still comparing against every single entry. If you store the entries in a structure that provides for efficient search without comparing against every single entry, like a hash table, the performance benefit would be even greater.

Comment: Can you provide any example of those structure that provides for efficient search?

Comment: I suggested a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and that's probably the most natural choice. Since the order doesn't matter, your choice to pay the high price of keeping them in order is paying off nothing.

Comment: is there a implementation of hash table on some library of linux?

Comment: For C++, there's Boost which includes an unordered map class. For C, there are lots of choices, I'm just not sure how good any of them are. You can look at [uthash](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/) or [strmap](http://pokristensson.com/strmap.html).

Comment: Linux has built-in hash routines: do "man hsearch".  It's way faster than your linear scan.  There may be faster libraries out there, but we're talking about just a few strcmp()s or less to locate an entry, so you probably won't notice any difference.